# Filter SELECT result in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query about such a structure:

```sql
SELECT distinct
    ...,
    ...,
    (CASE WHEN 
        (select ... from ... where ...) 
    IS NULL 
        THEN 'Site' ||LOWER((
            select ... from ... where ... and ...))
    ELSE 
            (select ... 
            from ...
            where ...)
  END) as importantResult
FROM
  ...
WHERE
  ...
```

And now i need to filter only one value from result of importantResult. I cannot specify this in WHERE.

What i should do?

Comment: Is your subqueries corelated? As this can be achieved via  joins too.

Comment: @Popeye How use join to filter main select result?

Comment: Three sub queries can be converted to left joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "this" as a CTE; then filter.

For example:

```
with temp as
  (select distinct ... <your query goes here>
          ... as importantResult
   from ...
  )
select whatever
from temp
where importantResult = some_value
```